# sqlalchemy new style with Mapped anotations causes sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not interpret annotation Mapped chicken-egg-issue

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am following the example from sqlalchemy docs https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/inheritance.html#relationships-with-joined-inheritance

and I am facing this kind of chicken-egg-issue with  Mapped[List[Manager]] before actuall Manager class definition what leads to:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not interpret annotation
> Mapped[List[Manager]].  Check that it uses names that are correctly
> imported at the module level. See chained stack trace for more hints.

**what is the proper way to define and then import and create the tables with this new style with Mapped annotate?**

all the details:

I store them in models.py

```py
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    managers: Mapped[List[Manager]] = relationship(back_populates="company")


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    type: Mapped[str]

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "employee",
        "polymorphic_on": "type",
    }


class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = "manager"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("employee.id"), primary_key=True)
    manager_name: Mapped[str]

    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("company.id"))
    company: Mapped[Company] = relationship(back_populates="managers")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "manager",
    }


class Engineer(Employee):
    ...
```

inside database.py

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, declarative_base



engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://datalake:password@localhost/flask_db')
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

Base.__table_args__ = (
        {'schema': 'metadata'}
    )


def init_db():
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    import models
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

and inside app.py

```py
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from database import init_db
    init_db()
    return app


app = create_app()



@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>'
```

when running flask run I get:

**sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not interpret annotation Mapped[List[Manager]].  Check that it uses names that are correctly imported at the module level. See chained stack trace for more hints.**

the full stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/spike/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1064, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 92, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 912, in run_command
    raise e from None
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 898, in run_command
    app = info.load_app()
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 309, in load_app
    app = locate_app(import_name, name)
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/andi/Projects/sqlalchemy_spike/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/Users/andi/Projects/sqlalchemy_spike/app.py", line 7, in create_app
    init_db()
  File "/Users/andi/Projects/sqlalchemy_spike/database.py", line 22, in init_db
    import models
  File "/Users/andi/Projects/sqlalchemy_spike/models.py", line 14, in <module>
    class Company(Base):
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_api.py", line 195, in __init__
    _as_declarative(reg, cls, dict_)
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 247, in _as_declarative
    return _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(registry, cls, dict_, None, {})
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 328, in setup_mapping
    return _ClassScanMapperConfig(
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 563, in __init__
    self._scan_attributes()
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 1006, in _scan_attributes
    collected_annotation = self._collect_annotation(
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py", line 1277, in _collect_annotation
    extracted = _extract_mapped_subtype(
  File "/Users/andi/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/spike/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/util.py", line 2353, in _extract_mapped_subtype
    raise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not interpret annotation Mapped[List[Manager]].  Check that it uses names that are correctly imported at the module level. See chained stack trace for more hints.
```

using:

```
Flask==3.0.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation - where you need to reference a type before it is declared - you can make a [forward declaration](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#step-four-remove-orm-mapped-column-directives-where-no-longer-needed) by passing the type as a string (note that you also need to import `List` from the `typing` module to complete the type hint.

```py
from typing import List
...
class Company(Base):
    ...
    managers: Mapped[List["Manager"]] = relationship(back_populates="company")
```

Comment: this results in similar error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not interpret annotation Mapped[List['Manager']].  Check that it uses names that are correctly imported at the module level. See chained stack trace for more hints.`

Comment: The traceback contains `from models import Employee` but I don't see that line in the example code.  Does the example code repro the error? Or alternatively, if you import `models` and access as `models.Employee` etc does that work?

Comment: sorry there were two tracebacks pasted. I corrected it. Earlier one was relaying on another import shape, but anyway it dosen't change a lot if there is `import models` or seperate class imports

Comment: Hmm, I either get a `NameError` if it's unquoted, or it just works (with some minor adjustments for the not-public schema). This is with an equivalent database.py and models.py, and assuming models is importing Base from database.

Comment: what python version are you running? How did you annotate it? Did you put schema inside anotation - this sounds for me wired here as its so far down the road to db than python code.

Comment: 3.12.  I used this code to attempt to reproduce https://pastebin.com/1Ne66bqH

Comment: the needed part was using  `from typing import List` instead of using `from __future__ import annotations`. If you add that import to your answer, I will accept it.